# Sump pumps, flooding and water tables

Tags: basement, sump-pump, flooding, french-drain, rain

So we built an addition to our home in CT in an area with a notoriously high water table. We built a 9 foot deep basement in the hopes of having a golf simulator some day. We have footing drains that lead to an external sump pump pit. 6 months ago we had about an inch of water after a heavy rain storm. The sump hadn't kicked on but after we manually ran it the water in basement receded significantly and was basically just a damp floor. We figured the sump failed so we replaced with with an industrial dewatering pump with a backup.

This week we came home from vacation to water again in the basement from a big rainstorm. There is one spot where the water seems to be seeping in. The ground outside that wall seems to always get very saturated and is not draining water well. Also seems like the new pump for some reason is not kicking on. If I switch it to manual it will dump water for 30 minutes straight. But it doesn't seem to trigger on its own. I have been turning it on and off through the day to give it a break. But every time I run it water just pours out. It's draining to about 20-30 feet away from the house.

So considering this is happening again with the pump do I again have a faulty pump or is the water table just too high? I am going to do some exploration of the downspouts in the area that seems saturated outside, considering adding some French drains around that section of the exterior house. I am also going to bite the bullet and install an interior French drain and second interior pump in the basement area that keeps flooding. The guy who does this guarantees no more water in the basement with this interior
system. Any thoughts? Very annoying problem.

Comment: We need a lot more info on your pump to know why it's likely not triggering automatically.  Pictures would really help, along with a description and picture of what float mechanism is attached to the pump that triggers it to run.

Comment: Depending on the type of float switch and how it's installed, (pictures would be a good thing to [edit] in) it's possible to the point of being a common issue to have them hang up and not work correctly. If the pump pumps, it's the float switch or whatever circuitry is connected to it, not the pump. The "free-floating" type are QUITE sensitive to how and where they are attached, for instance.

Comment: [edit] your question to ask about why the pump isn't kicking in. Then, [ask a whole new question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about why you're getting so much water in the basement.

Comment: Sounds like the float switch needs to be adjusted.